# How to apply filter to group in crossfilter

Tags: javascript, aggregate, crossfilter

I have a situation where I am trying to do some aggregation with filters using crossfilter.  My problem is that I cannot seem to get the filters to work they way I would like.

The data that I have is basically source -> target edge data, where there are some self loops.  What I want to do is compute a sum over values for two cases 1. all self loops i.e. source_level2_cohort === target_level2_cohort and 2. all other loops i.e. source_level2_cohort != target_level2_cohort.  I am going to use the aggregated dataset to build a custom viz in using d3.

I am setting filters on the dataset using a crossfilter dimension that returns true if the source... === target..., it doesn't seem to be working.

Here is what I tried to do (see below).  I don't understand why the last 3 console.log() statements all produce the same output when I am changing the filter inbetween them.  Does anyone know why I seem unable to use the filter in this way?

```
function aggregateChanges(data){
  cf = crossfilter(data);

  var cnt = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.cid_cnt;});
  var cntGrp = cnt.group();
  var revenue = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.revenue_sum;});
  var revenueGrp = revenue.group();
  var srcL2 = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.source_level2_cohort;});
  var srcL2Grp = srcL2.group();
  var tgtL2 = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.target_level2_cohort;});
  var tgtL2Grp = tgtL2.group();
  var isSelf = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.source_level2_cohort === d.target_level2_cohort;});
  var isSelfGrp = isSelf.group();

  // example 1
  // isSelf.filter(true);
  // var selfRevenue = srcL2Grp.reduceSum(function(d){ return d.revenue_sum}).all();
  // console.log("self revenue: ");
  // console.log(selfRevenue);

  // example 2
  isSelf.filter(false);
  var otherRevenue = srcL2Grp.reduceSum(function(d){ return d.revenue_sum}).all();
  console.log("other revenue: ");
  console.log(otherRevenue);
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Sledge/pnkryhud/5/

Update:

Here is a better description.  If I uncomment example2, here is the output:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
0
:
Object
key
:
"cohort6"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
key
:
"cohort7"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
key
:
"cohort8"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

If I uncomment example 1, here is the output:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
Object
key
:
"cohort6"
value
:
10000
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
key
:
"cohort7"
value
:
10000
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
key
:
"cohort8"
value
:
10000
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

However, if I uncomment both, here is what I get:

```
:
Object
key
:
"cohort6"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
key
:
"cohort7"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
key
:
"cohort8"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)


Object
key
:
"cohort6"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
1
:
Object
key
:
"cohort7"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
2
:
Object
key
:
"cohort8"
value
:
24
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
3
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

It's as if the second calculation overwrites the first.

EDIT: updated the code alot.  Simplified to show wonky behavior.

Comment: I know that I cannot aggregate over the same dimension that I filter over, which is why I created the isSelf dimension.  Still doesn't work though and I'm beating my head against the wall over it.

Comment: In your working example, the outputs on all groups except `isSelfGrp` are different if you comment out your filter row `isSelf.filter(function(d){return d === true;});`. Crossfilter is stateful, so every time you call `group.all` or `group.top` you will get the current reality in terms of the filters in place on the whole Crossfilter object at that time.